# Ruby Rails update_all on particular user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: User and Book (user has_many books, each book has a price). I want to change all prices for a particular user.

I tried this:

```
def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    Book.update_all({:price => 0}, {:id => user.books})
end
```

(currently it only updates one book of particular user)

The url looks like this:

```
localhost:3000/users/103/account
```

I guess I need to grab the user id from the url also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Book.where(:id=> user.books).update_all(:price => 0)
```

The [old version](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class) of `update_all`, with the second "conditions" parameter, is deprecated. This is the [newer version](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all).

Answer (score 1):

```
def update
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.books.update_all({:price => 0})
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  # what happens if user doesn't exist?
end
```